# How to transform data using Lodash

Tags: javascript, collections, lodash

I dont have much experince with lodash and I want to transform my data. 
I tried using groupBy and map but i am unable to get the expected result.
Would greatly appreciate if someone could help.

**Sample Data**

```js
var sample = [{
    "changeType": 1,
    "type": "changeAccount",
    "updated": {
      "id": 71,
      "company": 124201,
      "user": 8622
    }
  },
  {
    "changeType": 2,
    "type": "changeAccount",
    "updated": {
      "id": 70,
      "company": 124201,
      "user": 8622
    }
  },
  {
    "changeType": 1,
    "type": "changeproduct",
    "updated": {
      "id": 15,
      "company": 124201,
      "user": 8622
    }
  }
]

// what I tried
var result = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(sample, "type"), x => x.map(y => _.omit(y, "changeType")));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

**Expected Result**

```
var output = [
  {
    "type": "changeAccount",
    1: [{
      "updated": 'for changeType 1 under type changeAccount
    }],
    2: [{
      "updated": for changeType 2 under type changeAccount
    }]
  },

  {
    "type": "changeProduct",
    1: [{
      "updated": for changeType 1 under type changeProduct
    }]
  }
]
```

**Expected Result 2**

```
const sample2 = [
  {type:"changeAccount", changeType: [{1:[{updated}],{2:[{updated}]}}] 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `_.groupBy()` the `type`, map the items to objects, and get the `changeType` properties by grouping again by `changeType`, mapping the items to take just updated, and spreading the results:

```js
const { map, groupBy, mapValues, pick } = _

const fn = arr =>
  map(groupBy(arr, 'type'), (group, type) => ({ // group and map to array of objects
    type,
    ...mapValues( // spread after mapping the values to extract updated
      groupBy(group, 'changeType'), // group again by changeType
      items => items.map(item => pick(item, 'updated') // extract the updated from each item
    ))
  }))

const sample = [{"changeType":1,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":71,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":2,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":70,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":1,"type":"changeproduct","updated":{"id":15,"company":124201,"user":8622}}]

const result = fn(sample)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

To get expected you'll need to use the same logic used for the `type` objects:

```js
const { map, groupBy, mapValues, pick } = _

const fn = arr =>
  map(groupBy(arr, 'type'), (group, type) => ({ // group and map to array of objects
    type,
    changeTypes: map( // spread after mapping the values to extract updated
      groupBy(group, 'changeType'), // group again by changeType
      (items, changeType) => ({
        changeType,
        updated: items.map(item => item.updated) // extract the updated from each item
      })
    )
  }))

const sample = [{"changeType":1,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":71,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":2,"type":"changeAccount","updated":{"id":70,"company":124201,"user":8622}},{"changeType":1,"type":"changeproduct","updated":{"id":15,"company":124201,"user":8622}}]

const result = fn(sample)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Ori thank you so much for your answer this is what i was expecting, can i also know what do i need to change to move changeType 1 or 2 under type. Right now thy are in flat structure

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please update the expected results

Comment: I added a Expected Result 2 and I accepted your first answer. The second result will clarify the output better

Comment: Expected 2 is not realistic. You'll need to assign the array to a key, `changeTypes` for example.

Comment: I would also remove the `updated` property of each object. See expected 2 result.

Comment: I see, I updated Expected Result 2 will that be possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204006/discussion-between-alexandra-and-ori-drori).

Comment: I wouldn't use this structure either. It's hard to parse after wards - `[{ 1: {} }, { 2: {} }]`.